# UITableView - gap between main header and section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Working on a `UITableView`, with a header in both the main tableview and each section. However, we are getting a weird gap between these two headers. We have tried the solutions given in other SO answers, such as:

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout`

`tableView.contentInset`

`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

But no luck!

I've put together a screenshot of what's happening:

[image]

The issue is the gap between the red and green headers, any help much appreciated, happy to share further snippets of the code if needed. The highlighted areas are matched in the view debugger, so I have confirmed it isn't an issue of extra padding anywhere.

Some relevant code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionHeader = ShareScreenSectionHeaderView()
    let title = viewData.sections[section].sectionTitle
    let subtitle = viewData.sections[section].sectionSubtitle
    sectionHeader.update(title: title, subtitle: subtitle)
    return sectionHeader
}
```

The header set for the table view is a `UIView`, set using the `tableHeaderView` property

Comment: use `heightForHeaderInSection` method

Comment: remove the header and footer value from storyboard

Comment: Code snippet could help

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan what part of the table view setup would you like to see?

Comment: UItableview, delegate methods.

Comment: @MAhipalSingh we don't use storyboards, all using Cartography - We need to have the header as that view at the top needs to be in the scrollable content

Comment: Are you adding the header view dynamically or are using the uiview

Comment: it's set here         self.tableView.tableHeaderView = titleView
where title view is a UIView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170382/discussion-between-vinaykrishnan-and-niamh).

Answer (score 1):

[image: There is no gap between the headerview and section header]
[image: The Xib of the tableview and UIView]

Here is the code snippet

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblLoad;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *lbltblHeader;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
   self.tblLoad.tableHeaderView = self.lbltblHeader;
   self.tblLoad.delegate = self;
   self.tblLoad.dataSource= self;
  [self.tblLoad reloadData];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section ==0) {
        return 5;
    }
    return 1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 50;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *v =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 20)];
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor;
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 30) ];
    lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am the %ld Section ",section];
    lbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor;
    [v addSubview:lbl];
    return v;

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 100;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellReuse";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] ;
        //you can customize your cell here because it will be used just for one row.
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am the %ld Cell ",(long)indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;
    return cell;
}
```

> I have created a new test project to testcase ur scenario, but i was not able to replicate as you can see there is no gap between the headerview and section header.

Comment: ha, thanks! I'll take a look through this and see what's different :)

Comment: Sure, Let me know

Comment: What constraints do you have on your table header view?

Comment: As you can see from the second image "lbltblHeader" is a separate single view and i haven't set any constraint on it, u can tell me what elements goes inside the headerview. I will try to add them and give constraints